# How to make code that deletes row if the date is older

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a tool that needs to delete rows that in the column "E" have dates older than 01-01-2019.

```
Sub OlderDateDelete()

Dim i As Variant

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For i = Sheets("Iberica Not Sent").Count To 2 Step -1
    If Sheets(i).Range("E2").Value < DateValue("01/01/2019") Then
        Sheets(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You're not deleting rows, you're deleting entire sheets.

Comment: I tried for searching the web, I got link probably related/analogue to your question.
See especially at paragraph "delete blank rows" and after. [Deleting a row with vba (in various cases)](https://excel.officetuts.net/en/vba/deleting-a-row-with-vba) I wish it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Watch this lines:

```
If Sheets(i).Range("E2").Value < DateValue("01/01/2019") Then
    Sheets(i).Delete
End If
```

Those lines will delete your sheet.

I think you should edit it instead as:

```
If Rows(i).Range("E2").Value < DateValue("01/01/2019") Then
    Rows(i).Delete
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest I come up with is to put the date "01/01/2019" in a cell, in my example in "G1"

Then convert each range to this cell and delete them:

```
Sub DeletePreviousYears()
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("Iberica Not Sent").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.DisplayAlerts = False


For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1

   If Range("E" & i) <> "" And Range("E" & i).Value < Range("G1").Value Then
       Rows(i).Delete
   End If

Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

The best would also be to use a Function to find the Last Row and come back up with your loop.
Also with your first code using `Sheets`, you were looping through sheets and not row.

Answer (score 0):

This is to answer your written question. You can use an `Autofilter` then delete all the visible data except the header row.

```
With Sheets("Iberica Not Sent")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
        With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<01/01/2019"
            On Error Resume Next
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Or, you can loop like this

```
Dim lr As Long
Dim i As Long

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lr To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "E") < DateValue("01/15/2019") Then
            Cells(i, "E").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
```

I prefer to use a filter.